# Ignore the content of a folder in an SSAS tabular project

Tags: git, bitbucket, visual-studio-2019

I have an SSAS Tabular project and I am working with Bitbucket, I am trying to ignore some specific folders in the .gitignore file like below (but I have a long list) :

```
/Assurance/bin/
/Delegue_Etablissement/bin/
```

The full path is C:\XXX\Delegue_Etablissement\bin\Data
I want to ignore all the files under bin for all the paths (dynamically).

I used `/*/bin/` but in vain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `bin/` (with no leading `/`) in your list of ignored patterns.

This will ignore any directory named exactly `bin` at any subdirectory level.

---

Quoting [`git help gitignore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format) :

> - If there is a separator at the beginning or middle (or both) of the pattern, then the
>   pattern is relative to the directory level of the particular `.gitignore` file itself.
>   Otherwise the pattern may also match at any level below the `.gitignore` level.

Comment: a small update : a *trailing* `/` will not "root" the ignore pattern to the current directory level, and will allow to ignore only directories (not files) named `bin`